# What's better for SEO for many international markets?

Tags: seo, geotargeting

Right now, we're working to migrate our company sites for international markets to this scheme

```
www.company.com/[2 letter country codes]
www.company.com/uk    #for United Kingdom
www.company.com/au    #for Australia
www.company.com/jp    #for Japan
www.comapny.com/      #for united states, and non identifiable.
```

However, in google webmaster tools, we can geo-target each directory, but not the root.  If we geo-target the root with US, all the other markets will inherit.

Is it better to move the US market to /us/ or leave it where it is?

Answer (score 1):

Is the primary market targeted for the US?  If yes, I would leave it as is.  The shorter domain will increase your hits on the SERPs and will allow you to keep whatever status is currently associated with www.company.com.

Answer (score 1):

I think by Geo-targeting all the other sub-folders you will be inferring the main top level domain be used for anything else and hence the US market.

I would not make a sub folder for the US.